# What is the maximum number of selenium drivers on service like AWS-EC2 or Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, selenium, amazon-ec2, pythonanywhere, pyvirtualdisplay

Using python-selenium and pyvirtualdisplay, I would like to open about 10 different Firefox browsers simultaneously on a remote server. However, on both AWS and pythonanywhere the firefox driver starts throwing exceptions at around the fifth opened window:

> WebDriverException: Message:The browsers appears to have exited before
>   we could connect

I was never able to open more than 5 or 6 window simultaneously on either service.
Is this a memory issue (isn't the point of the elastic architecture to account for this?)? A limit with the virtual display library?

There appears to be no issue if I try to open as many as 15 windows locally on my (very) old laptop.
Is there anyway around this without using multiple accounts?
Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800,600))
display.start()

Browsers = {}

for i in range(10):

    Browsers['br_%s'%(i,)]=webdriver.Firefox()
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am having the same problem on aws

Answer (score 0):

On PythonAnywhere, it's fairly likely that you're bumping into one of the limitations that we impose to prevent our users from trampling all over each other.